# drawable design 3 corners with one same color and else 1 corner with other color

Tags: android, android-layout

Colour Code : e32b0f, d03559, I want to design its background drawable please help me

Comment: Check this: https://developer.android.com/samples/GridViewPager/res/drawable/gradient.html

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: thanxxxx , that link solve my provlem@Brian Hoang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Try,
    int colors[] = { 0xff255779, 0xfcc6c0cd };

                GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable(
                        GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, colors);

                view.setBackgroundDrawable(gradientDrawable);

1. choose color and add color hex code in colors array.
2. GradientDrawable using and set orientation properties.[ex. GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM]
3. set view background [ex. Linearlayout.setBackgroundDrawable(gradientDrawable);]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. As much effort obviously has gone into this answer, it might be difficult to get a grasp at if it's just code. It's usual to comment the solution with a few sentences. Please edit your answer and add some explanation.